# What is the most efficient way to find the maximum value with sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I need to find the maximum between values in the SQL table. what is the most efficient way to do this in terms of memory and speed?
I'm using the nodejs sqlite3 module.

I know there is a trade-off between memory usage and speed, but I'm trying to find the fastest way to do that when the usage of the memory is the lowest in case the table is pretty big and the computer doesn't have enough memory.

for example -

1. I can send a query with `MAX(my_column)`.
2. Send a query for retrieving the whole column and find the maximum value in myself with help of the `reduce` function (or with a simple loop).
3. Use sqlite3 `each` function for retrieving the rows one by one.

Answer (score 0):

MAX(), in sqlite, on its own, is really fast and efficient. Pulling the data and finding max yourself could possibly be faster if you have a massively unindexed join, but I wouldn’t bet on it.

Running a python script calling sqlite max against one hundred million unindexed rows generally ends up in a result in about 0.001 seconds on my ancient laptop, your results may vary.

As for memory consumption, calling max in sqlite will not consume more memory than most other methods.

In the source code for sqlite3.c, you can see the step function minmaxStep, which appears to be a simple compare. I’m sure a tree structure would better handle more unique versions of max, but that would definitely take more memory.